# Loop returning unexpected results

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Am try to looping through a database result set, the problem is that i know i have only one row of data, yet the loop returns 5 rows
This is my method from my model

```
function get_latest_pheeds() {
     $data = $this->user_keywords($this->ion_auth->user_id);
     $keyword = $data;
     $user_id = $this->ion_auth->user_id;
            foreach($keyword as $key => $word) {

                $q = "SELECT *,COUNT(pheed_comments.comment_id) as comments
                FROM pheeds
                LEFT JOIN pheed_comments ON pheed_comments.P_id=pheeds.pheed_id
                WHERE pheed LIKE '%$word%' OR user_id='$user_id'
                GROUP BY pheeds.pheed_id
                ORDER BY datetime DESC";
                $result = $this->db->query($q);
                $rows[] = $result->result();

            }
            return $rows;
    }
```

What am i doing wroing

Comment: What rows are returned? the same row 5 times? or rows you don't know where they come from?

Comment: Its the same row being returned 5 times

Comment: We will need to see your db class as you do not have the actual mysql calls in the above code. Do you know if the foreach loop is executing multiple times?

Comment: What does `var_dump($keyword);` return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your query has an `OR` where it should probably have an `AND` - each query always matches the `user_id='$user_id'`.

This loop is quite inefficient anyway, I think you want to do something more like this:

```
function get_latest_pheeds() {
    $keywords = $this->user_keywords($this->ion_auth->user_id);
    $q = "SELECT *,COUNT(pheed_comments.comment_id) as comments
          FROM pheeds
          LEFT JOIN pheed_comments ON pheed_comments.P_id=pheeds.pheed_id
          WHERE (pheed LIKE '%".implode("%' OR pheed LIKE '%",$keywords)."%') AND user_id='".$this->ion_auth->user_id."'
          GROUP BY pheeds.pheed_id
          ORDER BY datetime DESC";
    return $this->db->query($q);
}
```

If you want your results returned as an array like they were previously, you'll need to loop over results and fetch each of them into an array key of another array. I can't do it here because I can't see your db class...

**EDIT:** Slight fix in the above code...

**ANOTHER EDIT:** another fix...

Comment: function user_keywords($user_id) {
   //Get all the user keywords
   $q = $this->db->select('keywords')
       ->from('keywords')
      ->where('U_id',$user_id);
     $words = $q->get()->result();
     $keywords = explode(",",$words[0]->keywords);
     return $keywords;
  }

Comment: thats the method that returns the words to check the pheed field against